# How to filter certain DataRows in a Data Table

Tags: c#

[image]

I have a DataTable like the one above, what is the efficient way to filter the rows

1. Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 should be matching with other row(s)
2. Col5 differs

something like below,

[image]

How to extract the rows which differs by the Col5

Thanks

Comment: to filter them in DataGridView? and do you mean to remove duplicates by the first 4 columns?

Comment: @Slai I want to extract the DataRows where 4 column values are matching and the 5th column value varies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may use ToTable(distinct, columns) method of System.Data.DataView. Below is the code sample:

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Col1", "Col2" ,"Col3","Col4","Col5");
```

Comment: I believe the above code return  unique rows based on the 5 columns. I need something like 4 columns are matching and the col5 value differs....

Comment: do you want to find which columns have different values?

Comment: @MSL I need DataRows whose Col1,2,3,4 matching with other row but Col5 differs...

Comment: BTW the column names are optional to remove duplicate rows `table.DefaultView.ToTable(true)`

Comment: @Touareg: I wrongly explained the scenario, but for the scenario i explained your answer remains true. So i will mark it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// DataTable dt = new DataTable(); for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) dt.Columns.Add("Col" + i); 
// foreach (var c in "EEFG") dt.Rows.Add(("A B C D " + c).Split());   // optional to generate the table

dt = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => Tuple.Create(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]))          // group by the first 4 values in each row (you can replace the numbers with the indexes or names of your columns)
    .SelectMany(g => g.GroupBy(r => r[4], (k, v) => v.First()))  //  group each group by the 5th value, and select the first row in each group, to get the distinct rows
    .CopyToDataTable();                                          // optional to copy the rows to a new DataTable

Debug.Print(string.Join("\n", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => string.Join("\t", r.ItemArray)))); // optional to print the result
```

If there are no other columns, it can be shortened to getting the distinct rows in each group:

```
dt = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(r => Tuple.Create(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3])) 
    .SelectMany(g => g.Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default)).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this and see the `k` and `dr` values

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { col1 = x["col1"], col2 = x["col2"], col3 = x["col3"], col4 = x["col4"] });

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var k = group.Key;

    foreach (var dr in group)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

My guess is as always with c# the most efficient with datatables is to use Linq:

```
var consolidatedChildren =
from c in children
group c by new
{
    c.Col1,
    c.Col2,
    c.Col3,
    c.Col4
} into gcs
select new ConsolidatedChild()
{
    Col1= gcs.Key.Col1,
    Col2= gcs.Key.Col2,
    Col3= gcs.Key.Col3,
    Col4= gcs.Key.Col4,
    Col5= gcs.ToList(),
};
```

<s>Although I'm not 100% sure this will return the Col5, but there should be a way to do that using Linq.</s>

**Edit :** Using children should be easier/cleaner.